# Trouble running a very simple Hello World JNI test

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface, codeblocks

**EDIT3:** It is defiantly the compiler flags causing the problem, if I compile from the command line using Microsoft's compiler it works fine. Does anyone know what I need to change in code::blocks to fix this issue?

When I run my code I am getting a UnsatisfiedLinkError. The load step works fine, i am getting the error when it actually calls the code.

Started with the path to my dll

```
java -Djava.library.path=E:\Java\JNIHellowWorld\PasswordGenHW\bin\Debug -jar dist\JNIHellowWorld.jar
```

The Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jnihellowworld.Main.HelloWorld()Ljava/lang/String;
        at jnihellowworld.Main.HelloWorld(Native Method)
        at jnihellowworld.Main.main(Main.java:16)
```

Java Code

```
package jnihellowworld;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main {
    public native String HelloWorld() throws Error;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try
        {
        System.loadLibrary("PasswordGenHW");
        String test = new Main().HelloWorld(); //errors on this line
        System.out.println(test);
        System.in.read();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

C++ header

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class jnihellowworld_Main */

#ifndef _Included_jnihellowworld_Main
#define _Included_jnihellowworld_Main
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     jnihellowworld_Main
 * Method:    HelloWorld
 * Signature: ()Ljava/lang/String;
 */
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_jnihellowworld_Main_HelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

C++ cpp

```
#include "jnihellowworld_Main.h"
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_jnihellowworld_Main_HelloWorld
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
  {
      return env->NewStringUTF("Hello world!");
  }
```

I am using Code::Blocks and GCC to complle the dll.

**EDIT: Here is the dumpbin /exports of the dll**

```
2    1 000011D8 Java_jnihellowworld_Main_HelloWorld@8
```

**EDIT2: simplified project to duplicate error using system.loadLibrary()**

Comment: Does it work in the more straightforward configuration?

Comment: Try copying the dll to the current directory and using  `System.loadLibrary("PasswordGenHW");`

Comment: Still has the error, I changed the example code to use loadlibrary.

Comment: Also if you are using `System.Load("absolute path to dll")' You don't have to specify it in path for `java`, I don't think.

Comment: @Bala R you caught me in between edits, i did not have the path set when I was using load.

Comment: I'm not sure then. Check out this post on [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/start.html). it has a very similar example and It has worked for me when I tried it.

Comment: Could this be a compiler flags issue? I have seen other people's post saying they have issues compiling jni if they don't use the correct flags.

Comment: These should be the flags for compiling JNI libraries: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html#native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just compiling by hand using the Microsoft's compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these flags on compilation and on linkage :

```
-Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at
```

Example:

```
gcc -c -Wall -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at test.c

gcc -shared -D_JNI_IMPLEMENTATION_ -Wl,--kill-at test.o -o mylib.dll
```